# Drum Synthesis Recommendations for OS X

Tags: drum, synthesis, plugin, mac

Hi all,

I love working with drum samples but to give rhythm tracks my own character I also like to layer up synthesized drums and manipulate the parameters in real time. Sometimes I'll make sounds by hand using an analog modular or something similar but more and more these days I find I am using software.

I'm looking for recommendations for good quality drum synth plugins for OS X (and also synths that are particularly useful for percussion).

So far I've found the following software interesting for various reasons:

[ImageLine DrumAxx](http://www.image-line.com/documents/drumaxx.html)

[AudioSpillage DrumSpillage](http://www.audiospillage.com/drumspillage.php)

[LogicPro Sculpture](http://www.apple.com/sg/logicpro/sculpture.html)

Anything I'm missing? I'm not too interested in 'realism' but I like a lot flexibility for creating original sounds and excellent audio quality.

Thanks in advance,
Iais

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the input. I'm leaning heavily towards Drumspillage - it has a deep and 'modern' sound to my ears and I'm coming up with some very interesting and original kits with it pretty quickly. Actually, I love it!

Thanks, Iais

Answer (score 2):

Matt's answer was the first two that came to mind to me too! Other than that, it might be worth having a look at http://www.soniccharge.com/microtonic too

Comment: +1 for the microtonic! And the Waldorf Attack too.

Comment: microtonics great!

Answer (score 0):

The first two that spring to mind are Kong (which is part of the  [Propellerhead Reason/Record](http://www.propellerheads.se/reason5/) package) and [Waldorf Attack](http://www.waldorfmusic.de/en/archive/attack.html) which is an older plug-in but works really well.

Comment: Waldorf Attack is the KING of drum synthesis. I haven't found a cooler way to do synthetic drum sounds.

Comment: Attack is great but bit me in the arse when I tried to use my Windows projects on the Mac. Never used it since.

Comment: That's weird, I have Attack working perfectly well as AU and VST on Mac. Did it lose your patches?

Answer (score 0):

Ooo ooo! Look at Stylus!

http://www.spectrasonics.net/instruments/stylusrmx.html

Spectrasonics have a very good reputation - My fellow sound designers have raved about Spectrasonics Omnisphere as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Logic Pro (You didn't mention what DAW you use), it has a built in drum synth/drum machine instrument called Ultrabeat

Comment: Hi, I use a number of DAWs including Logic. I like Ultrabeat but it's not for me really.